# Dynamically Register Generic Type

Tags: c#, unity-container

I want to register a generic Repository class using Unity.

This is my generic class:

```
public class Repository<TModel> 
    : IRepository<TModel> where TModel : class, IModel
```

TModel is a POCO object used with Entity.

If I register it like this it works.

```
IOC_Container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<Employee>), typeof(Repository<Employee>));
```

This would require though that I register each of TModel, which becomes cumbersome.

I have a bootstrapper that registers my service classes dynamically using reflection, and I would like to do the same with the repositories.

This is the bootstrapper code for the services:

```
var currentAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly);
var assemblyTypes = currentAssembly.GetTypes();

foreach (var assemblyType in assemblyTypes)
{
    if (assemblyType.IsInterface)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (assemblyType.FullName.EndsWith("Service"))
    {
        foreach (var requiredInterface in assemblyType.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (requiredInterface.FullName.EndsWith("Service"))
            {
                var typeFrom = assemblyType.GetInterface(requiredInterface.Name);
                var typeTo = assemblyType;
                IOC_Container.RegisterType(typeFrom, typeTo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Unity 3 supports [registration by convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec23).  Using registration by convention your example might look like:

```cs
var currentAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly);

IOC_Container.RegisterTypes(
    currentAssembly.GetTypes().Where(
      t => t.FullName.EndsWith("Service"),
    WithMappings.MatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default);
```

The above will register an `IRepository<Employee>` interface to a matching `Repository<Employee>` concrete type.

This can make life a bit easier when registration multiple types but for the specific Repository code you posted you might not need that functionality.  Unity allows you to register open generic types so in lieu of registering all combinations of IRepository you could just perform one registration:

```cs
IOC_Container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

When resolving `IRepository<Employee>` Unity will use the type Employee to resolve `Repository<Employee>`.